# Conditional concatenation Excel 2003: if text TRUE, add asterisk

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003, concatenation

[image]

`=CONCATENATE(A1)=IF(ISBLANK(F1),"","*")`
If there is text in column F (not just a blank space), I want to add an asterisk to the value in column A. I only want to see TRUE for H3 and H4 (H1, H2, H5 should be blank) and an asterisk added to the text in A3 and A4.

My Excel skills are quite rusty, but a Google search didn't turn up enough. I read half a dozen posts and reminded me of the CONCATENATE function, but my syntax is off. I would appreciate suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

In column A, append  `& IF(ISBLANK(F1),"","*")`
if it is pure text, enclose that text in `"`'s and add a `=` at the beginning.
          *[==> `="blaha" & if(...)` ]*

In column F, insert `=IF(formula,formula,"")` where "formula" is what you have there now.

Comment: Not sure what to make of your instructions. Column A is pure text (i.e. not the result of a formula). Appending your suggestion only creates a longer string "A00"  & IF(ISBLANK(F1),"","*")

Comment: `=` <- that thing, makes it a formula, leave it out and you won't get your asterisk. **"if it is pure text"** above. Forgot to tell in words about `=` ...